# is it possible to create a website and hybrid app (using ionic) with same codebase without rewriting anything

Tags: node.js, frameworks, zurb-foundation, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I want to create a website along with its hybrid app using Ionic, I checked ionic's documentation http://ionicframework.com/getting-started/, I created an ionic app for tabs but I also want to handle my website with it so that if the request is coming from web then normal HTML should be served with web frameworks like foundation and I dont want to repeat the code for mobile and web. when I checked the files generated by ionic, it looked like this

```
    <ion-modal-view>
  <ion-header-bar>
    <h1 class="title">Login</h1>
    <div class="buttons">
      <button class="button button-clear" ng-click="closeLogin()">Close</button>
    </div>
  </ion-header-bar>
  <ion-content>
    <form ng-submit="doLogin()">
      <div class="list">
        <label class="item item-input">
          <span class="input-label">Username</span>
          <input type="text" ng-model="loginData.username">
        </label>
        <label class="item item-input">
          <span class="input-label">Password</span>
          <input type="password" ng-model="loginData.password">
        </label>
        <label class="item">
          <button class="button button-block button-positive" type="submit">Log in</button>
        </label>
      </div>
    </form>
  </ion-content>
</ion-modal-view>
```

So is it possible to use the same code for web and app(foundation for web and ionic for app)

Comment: [See answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22870196/how-to-use-ionic-framework-for-web-app-development)

Comment: Thanks for the answer Jacob, but my requirement is something like if the code is running for app then it should use Ionic framwork and if the code is running on web (mobile+desktop) then it should use some other frameworks so that it should not look like an ugly mobile app running on web

Comment: You need to put all files from www into your document root of the server. 

If you made your code modular, you can switch the htmls and make it happen. (rewrite of html required)  Or you actually use the ionic grid to give the xl screens a different look.

Comment: It should be possible by now... [Serve Rails API and Ionic mobile website together](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36074227/serve-rails-api-and-ionic-mobile-website-together)

Comment: yes you can!
you can use ionic platform add browser
then you need to add to your node js server.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30286943/ionic-as-a-web-server

Answer (score 0):

yes you can!
you can use ionic platform add browser
then you need to add to your node js server.

[Ionic as a web server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30286943/ionic-as-a-web-server)