# How to write WebApp to reuse source code in Ionic

Tags: angularjs, mobile, web-applications, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

What should be requirements on source code of WebApp to be sure that in easy way we adopt it in Ionic's application. The question is inversion of [How to use Ionic Framework for Web App Development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22870196/how-to-use-ionic-framework-for-web-app-development)

There are recommended practises for Angular.JS ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good start is simply to write your angular app with good clean design and encapsulation of proper things into services and directives.

You should definitely be able to reuse many services.  I've even had a few directives work out by applying different CSS to them.